# Windows Application Load PDF file from memory Stream

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, stream

I would like to load a pdf file into memory stream and then it should be assigned  to
adobe pdf reader object like following,

```
axacropdf1.LoadFile(MemoryStreamObject);
```

I searched google but I am not able to understand it. so could some one please help to do this.

Comment: Why dont you save first in disk and then use `Process.Start();`?

Comment: The operation you want is not supported. You set the document to show by [AxAcroPDF](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.167.html) using its [Src](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.167.html) property which is *The URL for the document, formatted as a string.* Adobe here does not define URL any further but I don't think they support data URLs.